# Problema exportación/importación mysql para Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Estoy intentando montarme un proyecto que ya está hecho y funcionando en servidor en local. El problema es que cuando exporto la Base de Datos desde el servidor y luego la importo en local, durante la exportación me mete caracteres especiales `\n` `\r` adicionales en todos los saltos de linea en el archivo .sql.

El problema es que a la hora de montarlo, todas las configuraciones que están hechas de la tabla `wp_options`>`option_value` que van serializados no se montan correctamente, porque la serialización no concuerda con los tipos de datos que tiene debido a estos `\n` `\r` adicionales.

Esto ya me ha pasado desde un servidor linux y un windows. El ordenador donde lo estoy montando tiene windows 10.

No se si hay alguna manera especial de exportar para que no me meta estos caracteres adicionales o pasarle algún tipo de filtro.

Gracias

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53331/discussion-on-question-by-pablone-problema-exportacion-importacion-mysql-para-wo).

Comment: Evita phpmyadmin, hacerlo a través de una web tiene muchos puntos de fallo (complementos de seguridad del navegador, módulos de seguridad del servidor apache, firewalls L7, etc). Intenta hacerlo con los comandos que te dije y haz el envío de archivos entre máquinas usando scp o ftp.

Comment: Para descartar más interferencias en los datos.. ¿realizas algún tipo de edición en lo que te descargas? ¿has probado a decirle a phpmyadmin que te lo descargue en gzip o zip y subirlo tal cual sin modificar? Intento eliminar o detectar cualquier interferencia en el proceso que pueda ser el origen del problema.

Comment: @OscarGarcia probaré a ver si doy con la solución. Si consigo lo pondré como respuesta. Igualmente gracias a todos. Si se os ocurre algo más sería de agradecer.

Comment: @OscarGarcia si he probado a descargarlo de todas las formas posibles y nada. Sin abrirlo de ninguna manera y subirlo directamente y nada. Es un poco pesadilla

Comment: Cuando lo intentes con el volcado mysqldump, scp y luego mysql me avisas. Lo ideal sería ver un archivo para ver el error, podría de tratarse de un bug de phpmyadmin, pero tienes en ambos servidores versiones bastante maduras, pero supongo que son datos sensibles y no puedes hacerlo. PD: probando un volcado sólo de esa tabla tampoco te va, ¿no? Ya me contarás lo que sea. Si quieres puedes crear un canal de chat y hablamos por él.

Comment: @OscarGarcia como puedo crear un canal de chat?

Comment: Aquí: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53331/discussion-on-question-by-pablone-problema-exportacion-importacion-mysql-para-wo

Comment: @OscarGarcia he probado a hacer un `mysqldump --user=***  --password=** BD > copia_seguridad.sql`  en su servidor, luego me he descargado la BD mediante Filezilla y luego en local `mysql --user=*** --password=*** bd < copia_seguridad.sql` y nada, sigo teniendo el mismo problema.